# Defining convergence in topological spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, set-theory

In topology, we define continuity (I should be defining convergence to a point here, however) of a function at a point through for any (first) open neighbourhood containining the value of the function at a point, there exists a second open neighbourhood containing the point such that, for any other point in the first neighbourhood, the value of the function at this other point lies in the second neighbourhood.

I’m trying to generalise the proof at the end of these notes to topological spaces.

[https://www.ime.usp.br/~oliveira/ELE-IteratedLimits.pdf](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eoliveira/ELE-IteratedLimits.pdf)

However, I’m having trouble with the following. Suppose a function is not defined at a point, but we want to prove that it has a limit at that point, not that it is continuous. For example, $f:\mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$. How do we characterise the behaviour of this function as $x$ tends to $0$ in terms of a topological definition of convergence? Looking at the definition of continuity, this only speaks about neighbourhoods $U_0$ *containing* the point $0$, but the function is only defined on $U_0\cap (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})$. Could we perhaps, drawing inspiration from the definition of continuity and this example, given a point $p$ in a topological space $X$, define the convergence to $p$ of the value of a function $f$ whose domain $S$ is a subspace of $X$, as follows?

Given $f:S\subset X \to Y$, $a\in Y$ and $p\in X$ we say $f(s)$ tends to $a$ as $s\to p$ if, for any neighbourhood $V_a\ni a$,$\exists U_p\ni p$, with $\tilde{U}_p:=U_p\cap S$ (non-empty?), such that $f(\tilde{U}_p)\subset V_{a}$?

Moreover, is this definition standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of difficulty is standard.  There are many possible techniques to handle it; some textbooks explicitly talk about [punctured neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Deleted_neighbourhood).  IMHO, the simplest option is the following:

> Let $S\subseteq X$ and $x_0\in X$ be such that $x_0$ is an [accumulation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Accumulation_points_of_a_set) of $S$.  Suppose $f\in S\to Y$.  Then $\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(x)}=L$ iff the function $\tilde{f}:S\sqcup\{x_0\}\to Y$; $$\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) & x\in S\\L&x=x_0\end{cases}$$ is continuous.

In your case, $X=\mathbb{R}$, $S=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and $x_0=0$.  The [continuous extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_extension) $\begin{cases}x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}&x\neq0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$ is, in fact, continuous, so $$\lim_{x\to0}{x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}=0$$

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. Wikipedia says the following, could you please share some light why the below criterion is related to filters? “ Note that the domain of f does not need to contain p. If it does, then the value of f at p is irrelevant to the definition of the limit. In particular, if the domain of f is X − {p} (or all of X), then the limit of f as x → p exists and is equal to L if, for all subsets Ω of X with limit point p, the limit of the restriction of f to Ω exists and is equal to L. …”

Comment: “… Sometimes this criterion is used to establish the non-existence of the two-sided limit of a function on R by showing that the one-sided limits either fail to exist or do not agree. Such a view is fundamental in the field of general topology, where limits and continuity at a point are defined in terms of special families of subsets, called filters, or generalized sequences known as nets. “

Comment: @MartinGeller: That's really a separate question, but: in $\mathbb{R}$, each minimal subset $\Omega$ with accumulation point $p$ is of the form $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=p$.  In more general topological spaces, you might need a sequence that is too long to be indexed by $\mathbb{N}$; then you index it by a filter and the result is called a net.